# Approximation of a Function Discontinuous only at a Set of First Category

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a function $f$:$T$ $\rightarrow$ $R$ that is continuous except for a set of first category.

Brosowski and da Silva (1997) argue that there exist a sequence of continuous functions that converges to $f$ uniformly in any compact set in the interior of the set of continuity points. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02836263#page-1

But apparently their approximation does not provide pointwise convergence. A possible example is a function that has 1 on a rational and 0 at irrational on the set of discontinuity.

On the other hand, if we consider a step function in $R^n$ that takes a value of, say, 1/2, at a point of discontinuity, then there exists a sequence of continuous functions that converge pointwise.

I would like to characterize a class of functions that is continuous except for a set of first category and still allows pointwise approximations. I would appreciate comments and references.

Answer (score 1):

> a class of functions that is continuous except for a set of first category and still allows pointwise approximations

The first condition is redundant: pointwise limit of continuous functions is automatically continuous except for a set of first category. Such functions form [Baire class 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1). Several references are given on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/32039).

Comment: Thank you. Then it is about characterizing a class of functions that can be obtained as a pointwise limit of continuous functions.

Comment: @user Those are precisely functions of Baire class 1, about which much has been written.